# Curl of implicit vector field?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-analysis

I know I can check whether a given (continous-differentiable) vector field (with simple connected domain) is conservative by checking if its curl is zero. In the 2d case for example

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
z_1 \\
z_2
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
F_1(x, y) \\
F_2(x, y)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

so if the curl

$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial x} F_2(x,y) - \frac{\partial }{\partial y} F_1(x,y) = 0
$$

then the vector field is conservative.

But what can be done if the vector field is not available as a set of explicit functions but instead only implicitly (and it is not possible to isolate the expressions)? I.e. like this:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
G_1(x, y, z_1) \\
G_2(x, y, z_2)
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix} \tag{1}
$$

Or even like this:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
H_1(x, y, z_1, z_2) \\
H_2(x, y, z_1, z_2)
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix} \tag{2}
$$

**Question**: Can I still somehow check if the implicit vector field $(1)$ or even $(2)$ is conservative?

**Example**: I will give an explicit example:

$$
\begin{align}
z_1 &= G_1(x, y, z_1) = x^2 + y^2 + z_1^3 = 0 \\
z_2 &= G_2(x, y, z_2) = (x + y + z_2)^3 = 0 
\end{align}
$$

Implicit differentiation:

$$
\begin{align}
0 &= 2 y + 3 z_1^2  \frac{\partial z_1}{ \partial y} \\
0 &= 3(x + y + z_2)^2 \Big(1 + \frac{\partial z_2}{\partial x} \Big)
\end{align}
$$

Solve for partial derivatives:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial z_2}{\partial x} &= -1 \\
\frac{\partial z_1}{\partial y} &= -\frac{2 y}{3 z_1^2}
\end{align}
$$

Then the curl should be

$$
\frac{\partial z_2}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial z_1}{\partial y} = \frac{2 y}{3 z_1^2} - 1 \neq 0
$$

So in this case, the vector field should be not a conservative vector field. Is this conclusion and the derivation correct like this?

Comment: Try implicit differentiation?

Comment: @Rahul I updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, with the conditions necessary for the implicit function theorem. This is the generality I think you are looking for and mimics your computation with the explicit example.

Your goal is to compute 
$$
\frac{\partial z_2}{\partial x}-
\frac{\partial z_1}{\partial y}$$
And as long as $\frac{\partial G_1}{\partial z_1}\ne 0$ and $\frac{\partial G_2}{\partial z_2}\ne 0$,
$$
\frac{\partial z_2}{\partial x}-
\frac{\partial z_1}{\partial y}\\
=\frac{\frac{\partial G_1}{\partial y}}{\frac{\partial G_1}{\partial z_1}}-
\frac{\frac{\partial G_2}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial G_2}{\partial z_2}}
$$
Which are in general more approachable to compute.